# Device missing from View As: in Storyboard

Tags: xcode

I'm following a tutorial which indicates I should select iPhone 8 from the View As panel to change the size of the view controller in Storyboard.

iPhone 8 is not appearing.  However it does appear in the list of devices that I can actually run in the Simulator.  I'm running Xcode 11.5. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm speculating here, but since Apple discontinued the 8/8+ and the second generation iPhone SE has the same screen size as the 8 (4.7 inches), they most likely dropped it from Xcode. The 8 Plus still has a unique screen size in the iPhone line-up. You can use the SE gen 2 in place of the 8 for storyboard layout.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks very much!!